# What do the three dots mean in this problem? (Concrete Mathematics, ex. 1.9)

Tags: notation

Exercise 1.9 in Concrete Mathematics (Knuth et al.):

[image]

What does '...' between $x_1$ and $x_n$ mean? If it's multiplication, I would expect the dots to be centered. If it's saying that the inequality holds for each $x_a$ with a between $1$ and $n$ (inclusive), then I would expect commas.

Comment: Yes, it denotes multiplication.

Comment: As evidence that it denotes multiplication, notice that the following sentence is intended to prove $P(2)$ is true, and in that expression $x_1$ and $x_2$ are multiplied.

Comment: Standard ellipsis.

Comment: There are 2 instances of ... in the first displayed equation.  The first instance means"product of all the x's", and the second, after the "if", means "if all the x's are nonnegative".